# syntaxerror json.parse unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the json data undefine property in Opencart?

Tags: php, json, opencart-3

[image: pop up error message]

using opencart version 3.0.2.0. while confirming order this message pop up. order confirm not being done, here is the code where the 79 number showing the error

```
if ($reflection->hasMethod($this->method) && $reflection->getMethod($this->method)->getNumberOfRequiredParameters() <= count($args)) { 
    return call_user_func_array(array($controller, $this->method), $args); 
} else { 
    return new \Exception('Error: Could not call ' . $this->route . '/' . $this->method . '!'); 
}
```

where the 79 line code is `return call_user_func_array(array($controller, $this->method), $args);`

How can i solve this? no order proceeding...

Comment: These are two different error messages. `JSON.parse` is JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What should i edit at the 79 number line code. That showing error message?